# How to get next sibling of any type (including text ones)?

Tags: jquery, text, nodes

Consider such snippet:

```
<p>A little of <b>this</b> and <b>that</b>.</p>
```

And let's say my current node is `<b>this</b>`, I would like to get next sibling of it, meaning `and`, regardless it is plain text. When I call `next` I get `<b>that</b>`.

*I know the trick with going up to parent, filtering all text nodes and getting let's say the 3rd one, but it does not work for me, because the structure inside `<p>` can be anything, so everything is relative, except that I know I have to get next node after `<b>this</b>`.*

Comment: @mplungjan, nope, it works as regular `next`.

Comment: Did you look at my suggestion to use .contents()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this :

```
$(target).prop('nextSibling');
```

Be carefull though, you'll lose the jQuery reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the nodes

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/6xxLN/)

```
var $sibs = $("p").contents();
//console.log($sibs)
var $firstB = $("p").find("b").first();
var arr = [],cnt=0;
$sibs.each(function(i,obj) {
  arr.push(obj);
    console.log(i,obj)
    if ($(this).html() == $firstB.html()) {
        cnt=i;
        console.log("found",i,obj)
    }    
});
console.log(arr)
console.log(arr[cnt+1]); // shows " and "
```